# In Excel, how can I sort by the first value when there are multiple values in the cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an automatically generated spreadsheet in Excel. The values of one column are:

```
1, 184
10, 18, 90
102, 207
11, 13
2
20, 50
204
3, 120
```

(all comma separated values in a single column, as below)

[image]

What I need to do is sort by the first number, so that the above would be:

```
1, 184
2
3, 120
10, 18, 90
11, 13
20, 50
102, 207
204
```

How can i do this in Excel?

Comment: What version of Excel do you have?

Comment: Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2212 Build 16.0.15928.20196) 64-bit

Comment: Then my answer should work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Excel 365 current channel:

```
=SORTBY(A1:A8, NUMBERVALUE(TEXTBEFORE(A1:A8,",",,,,A1:A8)))
```

Comment: Or a littel less verbose `=SORTBY(A1:A8,--TEXTBEFORE(A1:A8&",",","))`

Comment: Or, may be this one `=SORTBY(A1:A8,TEXTSPLIT(A1:A8,",")/1)`